# Remove timestamp from matplotlib.num2date date, and use date stamp in axis xlabel

Tags: python, date, datetime, matplotlib

I have an array of date values (T_date), imported from a CSV and converted to numbers using

```
T_date, T_price = np.loadtxt('TESC.csv', unpack = True, delimiter = ',',
                 skiprows=1, usecols=(0,4),
                 converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
```

I then create a new array starting from 0, with 0 being the earliest date using

```
T_date0=T_date-np.amin(T_date)
```

I wish to label the x axis of a pyplot plot as

```
plt.xlabel("Date, 0 = ", firstdate)
```

where firstdate=

```
firstdate = mdates.num2date(np.amin(T_date)).
```

This creates a datetime value in the form Y-m-d time, but as my data has no time values I wish to remove it.

When I run this, I get the error

```
"AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```
plt.xlabel("Date, 0 = {}".format(firstdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
```

And for completeness: the error you're seeing is due to python trying to unpack the 2nd argument you've passed to `xlabel`, as per its definition:

```
Definition:  plt.xlabel(s, *args, **kwargs)
```

As for the question asked only in your title ("Remove timestamp from matplotlib.num2date date"), you should look into the formatting options of the xaxis. This [example from the matplotlib website](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html) sums it up very well. You'll need:

```
ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Hi @TomKeyte if this (or any other) answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this though. But having a higher reputation yourself, would give you more benefits within this community though.